# The name for numbers with a certain digit sum.

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, decimal-expansion

What is the term for a number that has a certain digit sum? For instance 12 is the "digit sum" of 84, 138, 525 and so on. But what kind of number is 84, 138 and 525 to the number 12? Is there a term or name for that?

Thank you in advance. Larry

Comment: I have never heard a specific term for such numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$12$ is just said to be the "Digit sum" of $84$, $138$, etc.

But there are no terms given for e.g. $84$ with respect $12$.